# Matplotlib x-axis dates on the endpoints

Tags: matplotlib

I am plotting my weather station data from my mySQL server. I am trying to figure out how to plot the x-axis endpoints (12 AM), but it only shows from 3 AM to 9 PM. Here are the most relevant sections of my code. I don't know if it's related to the fact that my first datapoint is at 12:08 AM and the last data point is at 11:52 PM. Any suggestions on how to show 12 AM at the endpoints?

[image]

```
import mysql.connector as connection
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

try:
  mydb = connection.connect(host=host, database=db, user=user, passwd=password, use_pure=True)
  query = "SELECT * from montvillestation WHERE ID BETWEEN 12327 AND 12469"
  df = pd.read_sql(query,mydb,parse_dates=['DateTime'])
  mydb.close()
except Exception as e:
  mydb.close()
  print(str(e))

df = df.set_index('DateTime')
time = df.index.to_pydatetime()

date_start = time[0].strftime('%-I:%M %p %b %d')
date_end = time[-1].strftime('%-I:%M %p %b %d %Y')

# Add meteogram location and time
station = 'FW2458'
axes[0].set_title('Meteogram' + ' - ' + station, loc='left')
axes[0].set_title('Valid: '+ date_start + ' to ' + date_end, loc='right')

# Format x axis
axes[4].set_xlabel('time', size=labelsize)
axes[4].set_xlim(df.index.values[0], df.index.values[-1])
axes[4].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%-I %p'))

xticks = axes[4].get_xticks()
xticks = np.insert(xticks,0, xticks[0] - 0.125)
xticks = np.append(xticks,xticks[-1] + 0.125)
axes[4].set_xticks(xticks)
axes[4].set_xticklabels(['12 AM', '3 AM', '6 AM', '9 AM', '12 PM', '3 PM', '6 PM', '9 PM', '12 AM'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listTry [`axes.get_xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticks) and [`axes.get_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels) to check the current values and labels.

To set new values and labels, use [`axes.set_xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks) and [`axes.set_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels).  Note that when you set new xtick values, the limits of the x-axis should automatically change to include those values according to the docs.

To do this for a generic date as in your example, use:

```
xticks = list(axes[4].get_xticks())
xticks = xticks.insert(0, xticks[0] - 0.125)
xticks = xticks.append(xticks[-1] + 0.125)
axes[4].set_xticks(xticks)
axes[4].set_xticklabels(['12 AM', '3 AM', '6 AM', '9 AM', '12 PM', '3 PM', '6 PM', '9 PM', '12 AM'])
```

Comment: That works, but is there a better way to make this more automated so I don't have to find the xticks each time I change the date? The 18725 represents April 8th 12:00 AM, and 18726 represents April 9th 12:00 AM: axes[4].set_xticks([18725,18725.125, 18725.25, 18725.375, 18725.5, 18725.625, 18725.75, 18725.875, 18726])
axes[4].set_xticklabels(['12 AM', '3 AM', '6 AM', '9 AM', '12 PM', '3 PM', '6 PM', '9 PM', '12 AM'])

Comment: I added a bit more automated way to do this based on your example / comment.  If this works, please use the green check to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: My mistake.  I wrapped a `list()` around the array.  Does it work now?

Comment: I needed to use np.insert(xticks,0,xticks[0] - 0.25) and np.append(xticks, xticks[-1] + 0.125)